# Online compiler usng Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I hope you won't get mad by this question.
I'm a relative beginner in Node.js and express.
I want to create an online judging system. It's like this; a person submits a code (a C, C++ or Python code), it is then compiled and run in the backend and the output is shown as a response.

Now before you say anything, please listen a bit more. I tried stuff like child_process exec and also some npm modules like compilex and compile-run. These work okay in my PC. However, the problem arises when I host this project on a platform like Heroku. The code doesn't get compiled (it is not supposed to, because why would Heroku have a gcc/g++ compiler?). So my question is, how would I create an app (where a user submits the code and receives the output as a response) using Node.js and successfully launch it in heroku and make it work.

Please point out any mistakes or anything that I maybe missing.

I hope you got question. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't have exprience with Heroku but it seems you need to deploy code directly for it to run. but you can try servers and services that give service with Dockerfile (like aws fargate or ... idk). you can build a docker container with whatever stuff you app needs and deploy it. Good things is that you can play with it locally and see how it behaves.

Comment: and I feel if you want to do something like this with node "child_process" might be the only option but you need to install dependencies first. and to isolate it from your host you can I guess run it in a docker container and send the logs to user or do something with it yourself.

Comment: @EricAska Hello! What did you deploying directly to run? The steps that I took to launch it on heroku, aren't those the deployment steps?
I'm sorry for being so lost, could you please explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: Well I never used Heroku but tutorial video shows that it tooks the code directly and runs it for you. this is very easy to use service but also limited at the same time. you probably don't have access to your server to install other packages (to compile c++). I feel that you can do this as you said with child_process but you need to first create an environment that makes it possible. as you said "it is not supposed to, because why would Heroku have a gcc/g++ compiler?" you need a server that runs your code and has gcc/g++ compiler installed.

Comment: Easiest way I can think of, is Dockerizinng you application.  but if you don't know how to use docker it will be  a bit tough start. so docker is like a small ubuntu package that you can choose what to install and how run your server, then when you build it, it will give you a "docker image" that can be deployed in different services with a command "docker run" or you can deploy it locally to test.